# MAMP Server could not be located in the dynamic link library

Tags: php, mysql, apache, mamp

I've successfully installed [MAMP server 3.0.1](http://www.mamp.info/en/mamp_windows.html)  on  Windows 8, but when I try to load a page, I've got many errors (shown in popup dialog boxes):

1. The procedure entry point php_body_write could not be located in the dynamic link library C:\AppServ\php5\ext\php_curl.dll
2. The program can't start because php_mbstring.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.
3. The procedure entry point php_checkuid could not be located in the dynamic link library C:\AppServ\php5\ext\php_gd2.dll
4. The procedure entry point php_set_error_handling could not be located in the dynamic link library C:\AppServ\php5\ext\php_mysqli.dll
5. The program can't start because php_pdo.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.

After that, start page (`http://localhost/`) opened and while I'm trying to open `phpinfo`, an error show again (5 times and consecutive).

I have AppServ on my computer too. My AppServ works well on my pc.

What may be causing the errors? How do I fix it?

Comment: MAMP is for Mac, WAMP is for Windows. What exactly do you have??

Comment: On Windows. `MAMP now available on windows`, see here http://www.mamp.info/en/mamp_windows.html

Comment: Why do you want to use it if you have such kind of problems with it? It is obvious that extensions are incompatible with php version provided. It also could happen because the mix of installs copied different versions of .dll into the system folder or along the path.

Comment: @Cheery MAMP is more easy to configure without edit any *.ini file. I'm interested and wanna try. Just it. So, any solution for my issue?

Comment: I told what the reason is. It tries to load extensions from AppServ, which are for another version of php (or compiled using another compiler). The problem is, probably, with the paths or wrong php.ini/*.dlls used by server.

Comment: @Cheery from `C:/MAMP/Conf/Apache/Httpd.conf`, i got `ServerRoot "C:\MAMP\bin\apache"`, 
`PHPIniDir "C:\MAMP\conf\php5.5.12\php.ini"`, and 
`LoadModule php5_module "C:\MAMP\bin\php\php5.5.12\php5apache2_2.dll"`. What wrong with it? What should I change?

Comment: The error messages are related to the php extensions loaded from another path (`C:\AppServ\php5\ext\ `). What is actually loaded you have to check by the results of `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` output. It will also show information about location of the config files.

Comment: @Cheery I Got AppServ path using `phpinfo()` on `Apache Environment`, `Environment`, and `PHP Variables`. Is there connected with my System Environment Variables?

Comment: So, which server are you running?? AppServ or MAMP? The running one depends on the started service.

Comment: @Cheery MAMP Server, I've already check on services.msc that my appserv service not running. Why i got appserv path on `phpinfo()`. Is MAMP related with Windows System Environment Variables? because I found AppServ path on System Environment Variables.

Comment: I do not know, I prefer to setup Apache manually, not with L/W/M/amp. So I do not know the specifics of MAMP, but tried to help to understand what might be wrong there. You have some weird mix of two setups.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By looking at issues with PHP extension DLL, most probably you already have another PHP version in your system path which conflicts with MAMP (or MAMP PRO) installation. You can check if you already have PHP in system path by opening command prompt and executing

```
PHP -v
```

or

```
PHP --ini
```

You can also check Help->Summary page in MAMP PRO which shows modules initialized by Apache server (PHP module and all PHP extension DLL's in Apache process memory map)

Comment: Yes, but what's the solution? What if someone isn't using MAMP Pro? What if they don't want to uninstall their current installed PHP version?

Comment: In my case there was a different php variable in system path.